# Android Two consecutive AsyncTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have 2 separate AsyncTasks that I want to run consecutively:

The first one tries to get the current location with GPS. While it runs a progress dialog appears. I dismiss the progress dialog on postExecute

The second one checks if a location has been found and tries to send the data to a remote server. Again a another progress dialog should appear.

The thing is that I want these tasks to run consecutively (first find the location, then send it). However I want the two tasks to be "independent" from each other. Which means I dont want to call one task from inside the other.

Which is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler and send the message in the onPostExecute of the first thread like this

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.arg1 = 1;
mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

where handler is

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler() { 

     public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
     launchMySecondThread();
     } 
};
```